# Bring task with activity stack to front knowing package name

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, stack

I have the following scenario.

I run application A with known packagename that starts Activity A1 as the main activity from the launcher. Now from A1 I launch another activity of this application that possibly is a settings activity or something else, let's call it A2. So our stack is A1-A2.

Now I switch back to the homescreen by pressing home. I start another application, let's call it B. B now wants to be able to switch back to the currently paused A application preserving its activity stack. That would mean we have B-A1-A2 at the end. Is that possible in general? Please note that I only know the package name of A and do not have any more information about application A.

Here is what I already tried without success:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(PKGNAME);
            if(intent!=null)
            {
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
```

But this gives B-A1-A2-A1.

Comment: You may want to print out your state and see if you are paused when the home is pressed.  It may be that you also have more than one copy of your activity running. By logging you can determine this. Which one is happening, in your case, is going to make the answer different.

Comment: "see if you are paused when the home is pressed" - what else could be the case here? there is only the other possibility that the app is stopped by the android system directly after pressing the home button. that is not the case because my B application is a taskmanager that shows running tasks. now i want to switch from the taskmanager back to the task A preserving the activity stack. should be possible IMHO. what i wonder about is that the flag does not reorder the task to the front, it just creates a new main activity over the existing activities.

Comment: if it is creating a new activity then if you save the state when paused, then you can just restore it when it is created again, and, if it is destroyed then delete the sate.

Comment: I asked if your activity was being paused, as, depending on what happens, your Activity may be killed, for example, if you rotate the phone. My point is you should realize exactly what happens, then, looked at the savedInstanceState passed to your activity and see if something there may help.  Don't assume, know what is going on, so you can know how to solve the problem.

Comment: @mad Any feedback on this matter? for Android 10 (Gingerbread 2.3.3) ?